# Same Origin Policy with Different port

Tags: php, ajax, same-origin-policy

I am having Tomcat Server running in localhost on port 8080 and have deployed my web application there.

Then my Wamp server running in same localhost with the port 80. The php code is deployed here.

I want to make a AJAX request from my html file which is there in Tomcat to php file which is there in Wamp server.

But because of the same origin policy, I am not able to access the php file. I have read the following post. But they have not given solution to  solve same origin policy issue with same host and different port.

Kindly help me on the same.

This is my PHP code.

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$hint="";
$itemName=$_GET["itemName"];
if($itemName == "ipad")
$hint = "Apple Ipad";
if($itemName == "nexus")
$hint = "Google Nexus";
if($itemName == "motog")
$hint = "Moto g";
if($itemName == "xperiap")
$hint = "Sony Xperia P";

echo $hint==="" ? "No Details" : $hint;

?>
```

and this is my javascript where i am making the ajax request

```
    function getDetails(itemName){
    request = createRequest();
    if(request == null){
        alert("Connection isuses");
        return false;
    }
    document.domain = document.domain;
    var url = "http://"+document.domain+"/Ajax/getDetails.php?itemName="+itemName;
        request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails;
    request.open("GET", url,true);
    request.send();
}
```

I have functions for createRequest and displayDetails.

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools. What does the JavaScript console say? What does the Net tab say? Can you see the Ajax request being made? Does it go to the URL you expect? Can you see the Access Control header on the response?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you browser is blocking Same origin as a security.

Did you try disabling the security? We can disable this security in Google Chrome as follows:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

Comment: Thanks.. this is working. But i want to use the programmatic approach as suggested by the following link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript